# Catalyst Request Upload - Truncating Files

Tags: perl, upload, request, catalyst

I am using Catalyst Request Upload to upload files with the Jumploader applet on the front end. Everything is fine for files under 10k or so. But if files are larger, I only get the last uploaded "chunk". Using `Data::Dumper` I can see the "10k bits" getting uploaded and each piece is put in a random temp dir. My question is how to upload the whole file and not have it broken up?

```
if ( my $upload = $c->request->upload('file') ) { 
    my $filename = $upload->filename;
    $target = "$file_path/$campaign/$filename";
    unless ( $upload->link_to($target) || $upload->copy_to($target) ) { 
        die( "Failed to copy '$filename' to '$target': $!" );
    }   
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Could you explain how do you read content of upload?

Answer (score 1):

By default, uploads in catalyst (done by Catalyst::Request::Upload) reads the content sent from HTTP and them save to a tmp file.

```
$c->request->upload('file')
```

Maybe Jumploader is sending bigger files with more than one HTTP request. So you need to debug to see what is happening.

You can start a server with "-d" or export `CATALYST_DEBUG=1` env. Then send one big file and see the number of requests that are done to the catalyst.

If it's is more than one, Jumploader may send something with the request, like an "upload file id" to make possible to you glue together all the pieces.